# Minimizing the absolute value of the difference of the sums

Tags: algorithm, math

I have an array with N elements (N is even): `[2, 4, 8, ..., 2^N]`. I need to split it to `2` arrays, each with `N/2` elements and get minimal absolute values of difference between sums of this arrays.

For `2, 4, 8, 16` answer is `(2+16)-(4+8)=6`. Can anyone explain to me the math side of solving this problem (no brute force)? Would the solution be the same if the original array is `range[1, N]`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks fairly trivial since `2^N > sum(2..2^(N-1)`. Hence, to minimize the difference, you want to put `2^(N/2)+..._2^(N-1)` in a different set than `2^N`.

Answer (score 1):

> *Would the solution be the same if the original array is range[1, N]?*

In the case of the array `1, 2, ... N` the answer is `0` or `1` depending on `N mod 4`.

- If `N = 4k` then the minimum difference is `0` and is attained (for example) by the partition:

  ```
  1 3 5  ... (2k - 1)              (2k + 2)         (2k + 4)                   ... 4k
   2 4 6          ... 2k  (2k + 1)          (2k + 3)         (2k + 5) ... (4k - 1)
  ```
- If `N = 4k + 2` then the minimum difference is `1` and is attained (for example) by the partition:

  ```
  1 3 5  ... (2k + 1)                    (2k + 4)          (2k + 6)          ... (4k + 2)
   2 4 6          ... (2k + 2)  (2k + 3)          (2k + 5)           ... (4k + 1)
  ```

The general case of an arbitrary array is known as the [partition problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_problem) [with constraint of equal size](https://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/33697/partition-partition-with-constraint-of-equal-size), proved to be [weakly NP-complete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_NP-completeness).